# Create variable that generates unique txt file then appends without creating another text file

Tags: php, html, forms, variables

I have a form that on submit creates a unique .txt filename and posts form data into that file.  That works well.  The issue is after it creates the file, I need a way to append it without creating another text file.  Because it is a form, when it submits, the code reruns each time submit is called and I'm not sure how to handle it.

Here is the form:

```
<body>
<form action="write_to_txt_file2.php" method="POST">
<input name="field1" type="text" />
<input name="field2" type="text" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
</form>
```

Here is the php:
I don't have to use the microtime as the unique variable name so if there is a better way, I'm open to changing it.

```
<?php

$myDate = round(10*microtime(TRUE));
$filename = "tmp/".$myDate.".txt";

if(isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) {
    $data = $_POST['field1'] . '-' . $_POST['field2'] . "\n";
    $ret = file_put_contents($filename, $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }
}
else {
   die('no post data to process');
}
?>
```

Comment: you could use sesssions

Comment: Yes, sessions are a good idea, I was just trying to keep it very simple at the moment since I'm rebuilding my classic ASP site in PHP ...and PHP is new to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you could utilize sessions also to this, set the filename if not set using that same generator, so that you could use it again after the next submissions.

Simple example:

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['file'])) {
    $_SESSION['file'] = round(10*microtime(TRUE)); // set a filename on initial load
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { // if submitted
    $myDate = $_SESSION['file'];

    $filename = "tmp/".$myDate.".txt";

    if(isset($_POST['field1'], $_POST['field2'])) {
        $data = $_POST['field1'] . '-' . $_POST['field2'] . "\n";
        $ret = file_put_contents($filename, $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        if($ret === false) {
            die('There was an error writing this file');
        }
        else {
            echo "$ret bytes written to file";
        }
    }
    else {
       die('no post data to process');
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['create'])) {
    $_SESSION['file'] = round(10*microtime(TRUE)); // creates another filename
}

?>


<form action="" method="POST">
    <input name="field1" type="text" />
    <input name="field2" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data" />
    <input type="submit" name="create" value="Create New" />
</form>
```

Comment: This is very nice.  I think I can work with it.  I will likely create the txt file from another page then click to get the form and have only one button on the actual form.  Thank you very much for such a head start!

Comment: you have no idea how much time this saved me.  I appreciate it so much.  I may need a little more direction in the coming days since PHP is not my native language so hopefully I will get more great solutions.

Comment: @Lori sure no prob, i'l reply if time permits